# Solving differential equation with products

Tags: homogeneous-equation

Consider the equation
$$\delta e^{\delta x}+ \frac{(1-e^{\delta x})(-ae^{-ax}+(a+\delta)e^{(a+\delta)x} +\delta e^{\delta x})}{(1+e^{-ax}+e^{(a+\delta)x}+e^{\delta x})} =0$$

Denoting $g(x)=1-e^{\delta x}$ and $h(x)=(1+e^{-ax}+e^{(a+\delta)x}+e^{\delta x})$, we can rewrite the equation:

$$-g'+g\frac{h'}{h}=0$$

or more conveniently:

$$gh'-g'h=0$$

We know $g(0)=0, h(0)=4$

I thought of maybe using the Laplace transform but then I recalled that I must use convolutions to transform a product. I tried solving without using $g,h$, and got monstrous expressions.

Any ideas on how to solve it? It's been more than 10 years since my differential equations course :(

(this is a follow-up question to [my original one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/544257/maximal-minimal-difference-between-output-probabilities-under-the-2pl-model))

Comment: So you have $(g/h)'=0$ which would give $g(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Comment: I don't get it, could you please elaborate?

Comment: You have $(g/h)'=(g'h-gh')/h^2=0$, so integrating gives $g/h$ is constant, but we already know $(g/h)(0)=0$.

Comment: Integrating does not help me here: this equation is the first derivative of a function whose extrema points I'm trying to find (see the link In the post)